# WKNavigationDelegate methods not called

Tags: swift, wkwebview, swift4.2

I'm trying to write a controller with a webview and I need WKNavigationDelegate methods, the problem is that these methods are not being executed at all.

This is my controller:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

public class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    private let webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        view = webView
    }
}

extension WebViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    private func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        debugPrint("didCommit")
    }

    private func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        debugPrint("didFinish")
    }

    private func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        debugPrint("didFail")
    }
}
```

This controller is being added to a top view controller using a container view, also the webview loads the website correctly. Has anyone had a similar problem or knows if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Did you tried adding breakpoints in each method?

Comment: @Shabirjan yes I did, that's how I was testing it

Comment: Ok just a hint, try to remove `private` from each `Delegate` methods and try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are adding `private` with `WKWebViewDelegate` Methods, Remove those like this and it will work.

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    debugPrint("didCommit")
}

 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    debugPrint("didFinish")
}

 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    debugPrint("didFail")
}
```

}
 [image]
Try this out, Also don't forgot to load URL in **WebView** or whatever you want to load.

Comment: That doesn't work and I'm loading the url correctly

Comment: Well i created demo project and these Delegates methods are all being fired.

Comment: The `public` visibility was necessary, stupid mistake. Thanks

Comment: BTW explicit marking these delegates `Public` are not necessary.

Comment: Are you sure Shabir? Have you tried that? I've tested without the public modifier and it doesn't work, XCode also presents the following message: "Instance method 'webView(_:didCommit:)' nearly matches optional requirement..."

Comment: Yes as you can see in my answer, I haven't use public keyword. Check my updated answer with screenshot.

Comment: Why extension vs implementing the method the ViewController?

Comment: @Claudio thanks, you're right! the private/public keyword made the difference. I thought it wasn't the solutions but it was. You should as a answer to gain points with this.